# Tamaño máximo de archivo en uploadFile windows service c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows-forms

Tengo el siguiente metodo para cargar archivosa traves de un web service, pero tengo un problema. ¿Como puedo aumentar el tamaño maximo de carga?, aqui en el metodo lo pone de 4MB, ¿Se puede dejar abierto para cualquier tamaño?

```html
private void UploadFile(string filename)

{

    try

    {

        // get the exact file name from the path

        String strFile = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename);

 

        // create an instance fo the web service

        TestUploader.Uploader.FileUploader srv = new

        TestUploader.Uploader.FileUploader();

 

        // get the file information form the selected file

        FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(filename);


        long numBytes = fInfo.Length;

        double dLen = Convert.ToDouble(fInfo.Length / 1000000);
 
        if (dLen < 4)

        {

            // set up a file stream and binary reader for the

            // selected file

            FileStream fStream = new FileStream(filename,

            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fStream);

 

            // convert the file to a byte array

            byte[] data = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);

            br.Close();

 

            // pass the byte array (file) and file name to the web service

            string sTmp = srv.UploadFile(data, strFile);

            fStream.Close();

            fStream.Dispose();

 

            // this will always say OK unless an error occurs,

            // if an error occurs, the service returns the error message

            MessageBox.Show("File Upload Status: " + sTmp, "File Upload");

        }

        else

        {

             // Display message if the file was too large to upload

             MessageBox.Show("The file selected exceeds the size limit for uploads.", "File Size");

         }

    }

    catch (Exception ex)

    {

         // display an error message to the user

         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Upload Error");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es posible configurar el tamaño máximo de carga de un archivo mediante las siguientes lineas, ya que por default es 4mb.

web.config

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="xxxx" executionTimeout="1600" requestLengthDiskThreshold="xxxx" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="xxxx" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Recordar que la cantidad se coloca en bits:

[para más información ver httpRuntime](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-2.0/e1f13641(v=vs.80))

Creo que si tu test de uploadFile es como el siguiente:

[image: testUploadFile]

debes tener un web.config ya que estas haciendo una instancia de un Servicio

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-any-type-of-file-through-a-C-Sharp-web-service/

Comment: y como seria si estoy trabajando con windows forms? en que archivo lo agregaria?

Comment: ya vi que es en el WS, yo lo estaba colocando en el proyecto de windows form